# PWA Project Site List Web Part Closed And Re-added - Datasheet View Disabled

Tags: list, web-part, project-server

On our PWA instance, we have a master template which defines the SharePoint Project Site layouts.  On this template, we have a list web part, which is editable in Datasheet View.

On a particular project, a user closed the list web part.  After re-adding it, Datasheet View is disabled. The tooltip reads - "This control is currently disabled.  You might not have the right permission level to use this, you might need to select an object or item, or the control might not work in this context."

I've ensured that List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> "Allow items in this list to be edited using the datasheet" is enabled, and tried toggling it off and back on to no effect.  I've also verified that I have permissions to edit the list - I'm logged in as admin.

I'm using IE9 and able to access Datasheet View on other projects (where the list web part wasn't closed) in the same IE instance, so it's not browser settings.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint / Project Server do you have? Instead of adding the web part again, I suggest you to re-open the closed one (if it was really only closed and not deleted). See https://marcellotonarelli.wordpress.com/2010/12/15/how-to-open-a-closed-web-part-in-sharepoint/

Comment: @pholpar Sorry, forgot to elaborate that it's SharePoint 2010.  Re-adding the closed web part resolved my issue - thanks!

Comment: OK, then I add it as an answer to the thread, so you can mark it as the correct answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the web part again, I suggest you to re-open the closed one (if it was really only closed and not deleted). See [this post](https://marcellotonarelli.wordpress.com/2010/12/15/how-to-open-a-closed-web-part-in-sharepoint/).